# Ti C6x DSP intrinsics for optimising C code

Tags: optimization, signal-processing, texas-instruments

I want to use C66x intrinsics to optimise my code .
Below is some C code what I want to optimise by using DSP intrinsics .

I am new to DSP intrinsic ,so not having full knowledge of which intrinsic use for below logic .

```
uint8 const src[40] = = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40};
uint32_t width = 8;
uint32_t axay1_6 = 112345;
uint32_t axay2_6 = 123456;
uint32_t axay3_6 = 134567;
uint32_t axay4_6 = 145678;
```

C code:

```
uint8_t const *cLine = src;
uint8_t const *nLine = cLine + width;

uint32_t res = 0;
const uint32_t a1 = (*cLine++) * axay1_6;
const uint32_t a3 = (*nLine++) * axay3_6;
res = a1 + a3;
const uint32_t a2 = (*cLine) * axay2_6;
const uint32_t a4 = (*nLine) * axay4_6;
res += a2 + a4;
```

C66x Intrinscics :

```
const uint8_t *Ix00, *Ix01, *Iy00,*Iy01;
uint32_t in1,in2;
uint64_t l1, l2;

__x128_t axay1_6 = _dup32_128(axay1_6); //112345 112345 112345 112345
__x128_t axay2_6 = _dup32_128(axay2_6); //123456 123456 123456 123456
__x128_t axay3_6 = _dup32_128(axay3_6); //134567 134567 134567 134567
__x128_t axay4_6 = _dup32_128(axay4_6); //145678 145678 145678 145678

Ix00 = src ;
Ix01 = Ix00 + 1 ;
Iy00 = src + width;
Iy01 = Iy00 + 1;

int64_t I_00 = _mem8_const(Ix00); //00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
int64_t I_01 = _mem8_const(Ix01); //01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08
int64_t I_10 = _mem8_const(Iy00); //10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 
int64_t I_11 = _mem8_const(Iy01); //11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18

in1 = _loll(I_00); //00 01 02 03
l1 = _unpkbu4(in1); //00 01 02 03 (16x4)

in2 = _hill(I_00); //04 05 06 07 
l2 = _unpkbu4(in2); //04 05 06 07 (16x4)
```

Here I want one something __x128 register with 32*4 value containg " 00 01 02 03 " data .

So I can multiply __x128 into __x128 bit register and get __x128 bit value .Presently i am planning to use _qmpy32 
I am new to this C66x DSP intrinscic .
Can you tell me which intrinsic is suitable to get __x128 type of register with 32x4 values with 00 01 02 03 values.

(means how to convert 16 bit to 32 bit by using dsp intrinsic)

Answer (score 1):

Use the _unpkhu2 instruction to expand the 16x4 to 32x4.

```
__x128_t src1_128, src2_128;
src1_128 = _llto128(_unpkhu2(_hill(l1)), _unpkhu2(_loll(l1)));
src2_128 = _llto128(_unpkhu2(_hill(l2)), _unpkhu2(_loll(l2)));
```

Be careful: Little-endian/Big-endian settings can make these sorts of things come out in a way you didn't expect.

Also, I wouldn't recommend naming a variable l1. In some fonts, lower-case L and the number 1 are indistinguishable.

Comment: Really!! Thank you very much .